# how to visually see the result of a constraint tested

Tags: visualization

Let `x+y==m+n` be an equality constraint where `sol={x->1, y->2, m->3, n->2}` is the list of values for the variables `{x,y,m,n}`. Substituting `sol` into the equality constraint generates `False` because `3 != 5`. My purpose is to visually see `3 != 5` rather than getting `False`, where `!=` defines  inequality sign.

Thank you for your help.

**An Example**

I have the following system of equations (212 equations) `system`.

```
system = {PM1 == EXR pwm1 (1 + tm1), PM2 == EXR pwm2 (1 + tm2), 
  PM3 == EXR pwm3 (1 + tm3), PM4 == EXR pwm4 (1 + tm4), 
  PM5 == EXR pwm5 (1 + tm5), PM6 == EXR pwm6 (1 + tm6), 
  PM7 == EXR pwm7 (1 + tm7), PM8 == EXR pwm8 (1 + tm8), 
  PE1 == EXR pwe1, PE2 == EXR pwe2, PE3 == EXR pwe3, PE4 == EXR pwe4, 
  PE5 == EXR pwe5, PE6 == EXR pwe6, PE7 == EXR pwe7, 
  PE8 == EXR pwe8, (1 - mtra1 - mtrs1) PQ1 QQ1 == 
   PD1 QD1 + PM1 QM1, (1 - mtra2 - mtrs2) PQ2 QQ2 == 
   PD2 QD2 + PM2 QM2, (1 - mtra3 - mtrs3) PQ3 QQ3 == 
   PD3 QD3 + PM3 QM3, (1 - mtra4 - mtrs4) PQ4 QQ4 == 
   PD4 QD4 + PM4 QM4, (1 - mtra5 - mtrs5) PQ5 QQ5 == 
   PD5 QD5 + PM5 QM5, (1 - mtra6 - mtrs6) PQ6 QQ6 == 
   PD6 QD6 + PM6 QM6, (1 - mtra7 - mtrs7) PQ7 QQ7 == 
   PD7 QD7 + PM7 QM7, (1 - mtra8 - mtrs8) PQ8 QQ8 == 
   PD8 QD8 + PM8 QM8, PX1 QX1 == PD1 QD1 + PE1 QE1, 
  PX2 QX2 == PD2 QD2 + PE2 QE2, PX3 QX3 == PD3 QD3 + PE3 QE3, 
  PX4 QX4 == PD4 QD4 + PE4 QE4, PX5 QX5 == PD5 QD5 + PE5 QE5, 
  PX6 QX6 == PD6 QD6 + PE6 QE6, PX7 QX7 == PD7 QD7 + PE7 QE7, 
  PX8 QX8 == PD8 QD8 + PE8 QE8, (1 - margin1) PA1 (1 - tl1 - tp1) == 
   PX1 \[Theta]11 + PX2 \[Theta]12 + PX3 \[Theta]13 + PX4 \[Theta]14 +
     PX5 \[Theta]15 + PX6 \[Theta]16 + PX7 \[Theta]17 + 
    PX8 \[Theta]18, (1 - margin2) PA2 (1 - tl2 - tp2) == 
   PX1 \[Theta]21 + PX2 \[Theta]22 + PX3 \[Theta]23 + PX4 \[Theta]24 +
     PX5 \[Theta]25 + PX6 \[Theta]26 + PX7 \[Theta]27 + 
    PX8 \[Theta]28, (1 - margin3) PA3 (1 - tl3 - tp3) == 
   PX1 \[Theta]31 + PX2 \[Theta]32 + PX3 \[Theta]33 + PX4 \[Theta]34 +
     PX5 \[Theta]35 + PX6 \[Theta]36 + PX7 \[Theta]37 + 
    PX8 \[Theta]38, (1 - margin4) PA4 (1 - tl4 - tp4) == 
   PX1 \[Theta]41 + PX2 \[Theta]42 + PX3 \[Theta]43 + PX4 \[Theta]44 +
     PX5 \[Theta]45 + PX6 \[Theta]46 + PX7 \[Theta]47 + 
    PX8 \[Theta]48, (1 - margin5) PA5 (1 - tl5 - tp5) == 
   PX1 \[Theta]51 + PX2 \[Theta]52 + PX3 \[Theta]53 + PX4 \[Theta]54 +
     PX5 \[Theta]55 + PX6 \[Theta]56 + PX7 \[Theta]57 + 
    PX8 \[Theta]58, (1 - margin6) PA6 (1 - tl6 - tp6) == 
   PX1 \[Theta]61 + PX2 \[Theta]62 + PX3 \[Theta]63 + PX4 \[Theta]64 +
     PX5 \[Theta]65 + PX6 \[Theta]66 + PX7 \[Theta]67 + 
    PX8 \[Theta]68, (1 - margin7) PA7 (1 - tl7 - tp7) == 
   PX1 \[Theta]71 + PX2 \[Theta]72 + PX3 \[Theta]73 + PX4 \[Theta]74 +
     PX5 \[Theta]75 + PX6 \[Theta]76 + PX7 \[Theta]77 + 
    PX8 \[Theta]78, (1 - margin8) PA8 (1 - tl8 - tp8) == 
   PX1 \[Theta]81 + PX2 \[Theta]82 + PX3 \[Theta]83 + PX4 \[Theta]84 +
     PX5 \[Theta]85 + PX6 \[Theta]86 + PX7 \[Theta]87 + 
    PX8 \[Theta]88, 
  PVA1 == PA1 - ica11 PQ1 - ica21 PQ2 - ica31 PQ3 - ica41 PQ4 - 
    ica51 PQ5 - ica61 PQ6 - ica71 PQ7 - ica81 PQ8, 
  PVA2 == PA2 - ica12 PQ1 - ica22 PQ2 - ica32 PQ3 - ica42 PQ4 - 
    ica52 PQ5 - ica62 PQ6 - ica72 PQ7 - ica82 PQ8, 
  PVA3 == PA3 - ica13 PQ1 - ica23 PQ2 - ica33 PQ3 - ica43 PQ4 - 
    ica53 PQ5 - ica63 PQ6 - ica73 PQ7 - ica83 PQ8, 
  PVA4 == PA4 - ica14 PQ1 - ica24 PQ2 - ica34 PQ3 - ica44 PQ4 - 
    ica54 PQ5 - ica64 PQ6 - ica74 PQ7 - ica84 PQ8, 
  PVA5 == PA5 - ica15 PQ1 - ica25 PQ2 - ica35 PQ3 - ica45 PQ4 - 
    ica55 PQ5 - ica65 PQ6 - ica75 PQ7 - ica85 PQ8, 
  PVA6 == PA6 - ica16 PQ1 - ica26 PQ2 - ica36 PQ3 - ica46 PQ4 - 
    ica56 PQ5 - ica66 PQ6 - ica76 PQ7 - ica86 PQ8, 
  PVA7 == PA7 - ica17 PQ1 - ica27 PQ2 - ica37 PQ3 - ica47 PQ4 - 
    ica57 PQ5 - ica67 PQ6 - ica77 PQ7 - ica87 PQ8, 
  PVA8 == PA8 - ica18 PQ1 - ica28 PQ2 - ica38 PQ3 - ica48 PQ4 - 
    ica58 PQ5 - ica68 PQ6 - ica78 PQ7 - ica88 PQ8, 
  QA1 == ad1 QF11^\[Alpha]11 QF21^\[Alpha]21 (1 + \[Eta]1), 
  QA2 == ad2 QF12^\[Alpha]12 QF22^\[Alpha]22 (1 + \[Eta]2), 
  QA3 == ad3 QF13^\[Alpha]13 QF23^\[Alpha]23 (1 + \[Eta]3), 
  QA4 == ad4 QF14^\[Alpha]14 QF24^\[Alpha]24 (1 + \[Eta]4), 
  QA5 == ad5 QF15^\[Alpha]15 QF25^\[Alpha]25 (1 + \[Eta]5), 
  QA6 == ad6 QF16^\[Alpha]16 QF26^\[Alpha]26 (1 + \[Eta]6), 
  QA7 == ad7 QF17^\[Alpha]17 QF27^\[Alpha]27 (1 + \[Eta]7), 
  QA8 == ad8 QF18^\[Alpha]18 QF28^\[Alpha]28 (1 + \[Eta]8), 
  QF11 WF1 == PVA1 QA1 \[Alpha]11, QF12 WF1 == PVA2 QA2 \[Alpha]12, 
  QF13 WF1 == PVA3 QA3 \[Alpha]13, QF14 WF1 == PVA4 QA4 \[Alpha]14, 
  QF15 WF1 == PVA5 QA5 \[Alpha]15, QF16 WF1 == PVA6 QA6 \[Alpha]16, 
  QF17 WF1 == PVA7 QA7 \[Alpha]17, QF18 WF1 == PVA8 QA8 \[Alpha]18, 
  QF21 WF2 == PVA1 QA1 \[Alpha]21, QF22 WF2 == PVA2 QA2 \[Alpha]22, 
  QF23 WF2 == PVA3 QA3 \[Alpha]23, QF24 WF2 == PVA4 QA4 \[Alpha]24, 
  QF25 WF2 == PVA5 QA5 \[Alpha]25, QF26 WF2 == PVA6 QA6 \[Alpha]26, 
  QF27 WF2 == PVA7 QA7 \[Alpha]27, QF28 WF2 == PVA8 QA8 \[Alpha]28, 
  QINT11 == ica11 QA1, QINT12 == ica12 QA2, QINT13 == ica13 QA3, 
  QINT14 == ica14 QA4, QINT15 == ica15 QA5, QINT16 == ica16 QA6, 
  QINT17 == ica17 QA7, QINT18 == ica18 QA8, QINT21 == ica21 QA1, 
  QINT22 == ica22 QA2, QINT23 == ica23 QA3, QINT24 == ica24 QA4, 
  QINT25 == ica25 QA5, QINT26 == ica26 QA6, QINT27 == ica27 QA7, 
  QINT28 == ica28 QA8, QINT31 == ica31 QA1, QINT32 == ica32 QA2, 
  QINT33 == ica33 QA3, QINT34 == ica34 QA4, QINT35 == ica35 QA5, 
  QINT36 == ica36 QA6, QINT37 == ica37 QA7, QINT38 == ica38 QA8, 
  QINT41 == ica41 QA1, QINT42 == ica42 QA2, QINT43 == ica43 QA3, 
  QINT44 == ica44 QA4, QINT45 == ica45 QA5, QINT46 == ica46 QA6, 
  QINT47 == ica47 QA7, QINT48 == ica48 QA8, QINT51 == ica51 QA1, 
  QINT52 == ica52 QA2, QINT53 == ica53 QA3, QINT54 == ica54 QA4, 
  QINT55 == ica55 QA5, QINT56 == ica56 QA6, QINT57 == ica57 QA7, 
  QINT58 == ica58 QA8, QINT61 == ica61 QA1, QINT62 == ica62 QA2, 
  QINT63 == ica63 QA3, QINT64 == ica64 QA4, QINT65 == ica65 QA5, 
  QINT66 == ica66 QA6, QINT67 == ica67 QA7, QINT68 == ica68 QA8, 
  QINT71 == ica71 QA1, QINT72 == ica72 QA2, QINT73 == ica73 QA3, 
  QINT74 == ica74 QA4, QINT75 == ica75 QA5, QINT76 == ica76 QA6, 
  QINT77 == ica77 QA7, QINT78 == ica78 QA8, QINT81 == ica81 QA1, 
  QINT82 == ica82 QA2, QINT83 == ica83 QA3, QINT84 == ica84 QA4, 
  QINT85 == ica85 QA5, QINT86 == ica86 QA6, QINT87 == ica87 QA7, 
  QINT88 == ica88 QA8, 
  QX1 == QA1 \[Theta]11 + QA2 \[Theta]21 + QA3 \[Theta]31 + 
    QA4 \[Theta]41 + QA5 \[Theta]51 + QA6 \[Theta]61 + 
    QA7 \[Theta]71 + QA8 \[Theta]81, 
  QX2 == QA1 \[Theta]12 + QA2 \[Theta]22 + QA3 \[Theta]32 + 
    QA4 \[Theta]42 + QA5 \[Theta]52 + QA6 \[Theta]62 + 
    QA7 \[Theta]72 + QA8 \[Theta]82, 
  QX3 == QA1 \[Theta]13 + QA2 \[Theta]23 + QA3 \[Theta]33 + 
    QA4 \[Theta]43 + QA5 \[Theta]53 + QA6 \[Theta]63 + 
    QA7 \[Theta]73 + QA8 \[Theta]83, 
  QX4 == QA1 \[Theta]14 + QA2 \[Theta]24 + QA3 \[Theta]34 + 
    QA4 \[Theta]44 + QA5 \[Theta]54 + QA6 \[Theta]64 + 
    QA7 \[Theta]74 + QA8 \[Theta]84, 
  QX5 == QA1 \[Theta]15 + QA2 \[Theta]25 + QA3 \[Theta]35 + 
    QA4 \[Theta]45 + QA5 \[Theta]55 + QA6 \[Theta]65 + 
    QA7 \[Theta]75 + QA8 \[Theta]85, 
  QX6 == QA1 \[Theta]16 + QA2 \[Theta]26 + QA3 \[Theta]36 + 
    QA4 \[Theta]46 + QA5 \[Theta]56 + QA6 \[Theta]66 + 
    QA7 \[Theta]76 + QA8 \[Theta]86, 
  QX7 == QA1 \[Theta]17 + QA2 \[Theta]27 + QA3 \[Theta]37 + 
    QA4 \[Theta]47 + QA5 \[Theta]57 + QA6 \[Theta]67 + 
    QA7 \[Theta]77 + QA8 \[Theta]87, 
  QX8 == QA1 \[Theta]18 + QA2 \[Theta]28 + QA3 \[Theta]38 + 
    QA4 \[Theta]48 + QA5 \[Theta]58 + QA6 \[Theta]68 + 
    QA7 \[Theta]78 + QA8 \[Theta]88, 
  QQ1 == aq1 (QD1^-\[Rho]q1 (1 - \[Delta]q1) + 
      QM1^-\[Rho]q1 \[Delta]q1)^(-1/\[Rho]q1), 
  QQ2 == aq2 (QD2^-\[Rho]q2 (1 - \[Delta]q2) + 
      QM2^-\[Rho]q2 \[Delta]q2)^(-1/\[Rho]q2), 
  QQ3 == aq3 (QD3^-\[Rho]q3 (1 - \[Delta]q3) + 
      QM3^-\[Rho]q3 \[Delta]q3)^(-1/\[Rho]q3), 
  QQ4 == aq4 (QD4^-\[Rho]q4 (1 - \[Delta]q4) + 
      QM4^-\[Rho]q4 \[Delta]q4)^(-1/\[Rho]q4), 
  QQ5 == aq5 (QD5^-\[Rho]q5 (1 - \[Delta]q5) + 
      QM5^-\[Rho]q5 \[Delta]q5)^(-1/\[Rho]q5), 
  QQ6 == aq6 (QD6^-\[Rho]q6 (1 - \[Delta]q6) + 
      QM6^-\[Rho]q6 \[Delta]q6)^(-1/\[Rho]q6), 
  QQ7 == aq7 (QD7^-\[Rho]q7 (1 - \[Delta]q7) + 
      QM7^-\[Rho]q7 \[Delta]q7)^(-1/\[Rho]q7), 
  QQ8 == aq8 (QD8^-\[Rho]q8 (1 - \[Delta]q8) + 
      QM8^-\[Rho]q8 \[Delta]q8)^(-1/\[Rho]q8), 
  QM1/QD1 == ((PD1 \[Delta]q1)/(PM1 (1 - \[Delta]q1)))^(1/(
   1 + \[Rho]q1)), 
  QM2/QD2 == ((PD2 \[Delta]q2)/(PM2 (1 - \[Delta]q2)))^(1/(
   1 + \[Rho]q2)), 
  QM3/QD3 == ((PD3 \[Delta]q3)/(PM3 (1 - \[Delta]q3)))^(1/(
   1 + \[Rho]q3)), 
  QM4/QD4 == ((PD4 \[Delta]q4)/(PM4 (1 - \[Delta]q4)))^(1/(
   1 + \[Rho]q4)), 
  QM5/QD5 == ((PD5 \[Delta]q5)/(PM5 (1 - \[Delta]q5)))^(1/(
   1 + \[Rho]q5)), 
  QM6/QD6 == ((PD6 \[Delta]q6)/(PM6 (1 - \[Delta]q6)))^(1/(
   1 + \[Rho]q6)), 
  QM7/QD7 == ((PD7 \[Delta]q7)/(PM7 (1 - \[Delta]q7)))^(1/(
   1 + \[Rho]q7)), 
  QM8/QD8 == ((PD8 \[Delta]q8)/(PM8 (1 - \[Delta]q8)))^(1/(
   1 + \[Rho]q8)), 
  QX1 == at1 (QD1^\[Rho]t1 (1 - \[Delta]t1) + 
      QE1^\[Rho]t1 \[Delta]t1)^(1/\[Rho]t1), 
  QX2 == at2 (QD2^\[Rho]t2 (1 - \[Delta]t2) + 
      QE2^\[Rho]t2 \[Delta]t2)^(1/\[Rho]t2), 
  QX3 == at3 (QD3^\[Rho]t3 (1 - \[Delta]t3) + 
      QE3^\[Rho]t3 \[Delta]t3)^(1/\[Rho]t3), 
  QX4 == at4 (QD4^\[Rho]t4 (1 - \[Delta]t4) + 
      QE4^\[Rho]t4 \[Delta]t4)^(1/\[Rho]t4), 
  QX5 == at5 (QD5^\[Rho]t5 (1 - \[Delta]t5) + 
      QE5^\[Rho]t5 \[Delta]t5)^(1/\[Rho]t5), 
  QX6 == at6 (QD6^\[Rho]t6 (1 - \[Delta]t6) + 
      QE6^\[Rho]t6 \[Delta]t6)^(1/\[Rho]t6), 
  QX7 == at7 (QD7^\[Rho]t7 (1 - \[Delta]t7) + 
      QE7^\[Rho]t7 \[Delta]t7)^(1/\[Rho]t7), 
  QX8 == at8 (QD8^\[Rho]t8 (1 - \[Delta]t8) + 
      QE8^\[Rho]t8 \[Delta]t8)^(1/\[Rho]t8), 
  QE1/QD1 == ((PE1 (1 - \[Delta]t1))/(PD1 \[Delta]t1))^(
   1/(-1 + \[Rho]t1)), 
  QE2/QD2 == ((PE2 (1 - \[Delta]t2))/(PD2 \[Delta]t2))^(
   1/(-1 + \[Rho]t2)), 
  QE3/QD3 == ((PE3 (1 - \[Delta]t3))/(PD3 \[Delta]t3))^(
   1/(-1 + \[Rho]t3)), 
  QE4/QD4 == ((PE4 (1 - \[Delta]t4))/(PD4 \[Delta]t4))^(
   1/(-1 + \[Rho]t4)), 
  QE5/QD5 == ((PE5 (1 - \[Delta]t5))/(PD5 \[Delta]t5))^(
   1/(-1 + \[Rho]t5)), 
  QE6/QD6 == ((PE6 (1 - \[Delta]t6))/(PD6 \[Delta]t6))^(
   1/(-1 + \[Rho]t6)), 
  QE7/QD7 == ((PE7 (1 - \[Delta]t7))/(PD7 \[Delta]t7))^(
   1/(-1 + \[Rho]t7)), 
  QE8/QD8 == ((PE8 (1 - \[Delta]t8))/(PD8 \[Delta]t8))^(
   1/(-1 + \[Rho]t8)), 
  YF11 == shry11 (QF11 WF1 + QF12 WF1 + QF13 WF1 + QF14 WF1 + 
      QF15 WF1 + QF16 WF1 + QF17 WF1 + QF18 WF1), 
  YF32 == shry32 (QF21 WF2 + QF22 WF2 + QF23 WF2 + QF24 WF2 + 
      QF25 WF2 + QF26 WF2 + QF27 WF2 + QF28 WF2), 
  YH1 == cpi tr12 + tr13 + YF11, YE3 == YF32, 
  PQ1 QH11 == (1 - sr1) (1 - ty1) YH1 \[Beta]11, 
  PQ2 QH21 == (1 - sr1) (1 - ty1) YH1 \[Beta]21, 
  PQ3 QH31 == (1 - sr1) (1 - ty1) YH1 \[Beta]31, 
  PQ4 QH41 == (1 - sr1) (1 - ty1) YH1 \[Beta]41, 
  PQ5 QH51 == (1 - sr1) (1 - ty1) YH1 \[Beta]51, 
  PQ6 QH61 == (1 - sr1) (1 - ty1) YH1 \[Beta]61, 
  PQ7 QH71 == (1 - sr1) (1 - ty1) YH1 \[Beta]71, 
  PQ8 QH81 == (1 - sr1) (1 - ty1) YH1 \[Beta]81, QINV1 == IADJ qinv1, 
  QINV2 == IADJ qinv2, QINV3 == IADJ qinv3, QINV4 == IADJ qinv4, 
  QINV5 == IADJ qinv5, QINV6 == IADJ qinv6, QINV7 == IADJ qinv7, 
  QINV8 == IADJ qinv8, 
  YG == EXR pwm1 QM1 tm1 + EXR pwm2 QM2 tm2 + EXR pwm3 QM3 tm3 + 
    EXR pwm4 QM4 tm4 + EXR pwm5 QM5 tm5 + EXR pwm6 QM6 tm6 + 
    EXR pwm7 QM7 tm7 + EXR pwm8 QM8 tm8 + QA1 (tl1 + tp1) + 
    QA2 (tl2 + tp2) + QA3 (tl3 + tp3) + QA4 (tl4 + tp4) + 
    QA5 (tl5 + tp5) + QA6 (tl6 + tp6) + QA7 (tl7 + tp7) + 
    QA8 (tl8 + tp8) + tr21 + tr23 + EXR tr24 + EXR tr54 + ty3 YE3 + 
    ty1 YH1, 
  EG == PQ1 qg1 + PQ2 qg2 + PQ3 qg3 + PQ4 qg4 + PQ5 qg5 + PQ6 qg6 + 
    PQ7 qg7 + PQ8 qg8 + cpi tr12, GSAV == -EG + YG, 
  QF11 + QF12 + QF13 + QF14 + QF15 + QF16 + QF17 + QF18 == qfs1, 
  QF21 + QF22 + QF23 + QF24 + QF25 + QF26 + QF27 + QF28 == qfs2, 
  QQ1 == qg1 + QH11 + QINT11 + QINT12 + QINT13 + QINT14 + QINT15 + 
    QINT16 + QINT17 + QINT18 + QINV1, 
  QQ2 == qg2 + QH21 + QINT21 + QINT22 + QINT23 + QINT24 + QINT25 + 
    QINT26 + QINT27 + QINT28 + QINV2, 
  QQ3 == qg3 + QH31 + QINT31 + QINT32 + QINT33 + QINT34 + QINT35 + 
    QINT36 + QINT37 + QINT38 + QINV3, 
  QQ4 == qg4 + QH41 + QINT41 + QINT42 + QINT43 + QINT44 + QINT45 + 
    QINT46 + QINT47 + QINT48 + QINV4, 
  QQ5 == qg5 + QH51 + QINT51 + QINT52 + QINT53 + QINT54 + QINT55 + 
    QINT56 + QINT57 + QINT58 + QINV5, 
  QQ6 == qg6 + QH61 + QINT61 + QINT62 + QINT63 + QINT64 + QINT65 + 
    QINT66 + QINT67 + QINT68 + QINV6, 
  QQ7 == qg7 + QH71 + QINT71 + QINT72 + QINT73 + QINT74 + QINT75 + 
    QINT76 + QINT77 + QINT78 + QINV7, 
  QQ8 == qg8 + QH81 + QINT81 + QINT82 + QINT83 + QINT84 + QINT85 + 
    QINT86 + QINT87 + QINT88 + QINV8, 
  fsav + pwe1 QE1 + pwe2 QE2 + pwe3 QE3 + pwe4 QE4 + pwe5 QE5 + 
    pwe6 QE6 + pwe7 QE7 + pwe8 QE8 + tr14 + tr24 + tr34 + tr54 == 
   pwm1 QM1 + pwm2 QM2 + pwm3 QM3 + pwm4 QM4 + pwm5 QM5 + pwm6 QM6 + 
    pwm7 QM7 + pwm8 QM8 + tr41, 
  EXR fsav + GSAV + sr3 (1 - ty3) YE3 + sr1 (1 - ty1) YH1 == 
   PQ1 QINV1 + PQ2 QINV2 + PQ3 QINV3 + PQ4 QINV4 + PQ5 QINV5 + 
    PQ6 QINV6 + PQ7 QINV7 + PQ8 QINV8 + WALRAS, 
  cwts1 PQ1 + cwts2 PQ2 + cwts3 PQ3 + cwts4 PQ4 + cwts5 PQ5 + 
    cwts6 PQ6 + cwts7 PQ7 + cwts8 PQ8 == cpi};
```

And the following data `bench` and `sol`.

```
  bench = {EG -> 727784.9503927924`, EXR -> 1.0390430275950355`, 
  GSAV -> 270413.4968362533`, IADJ -> 1.023809682164667`, 
  PA1 -> 1.0243216030460287`, PA2 -> 1.034337694370249`, 
  PA3 -> 0.996595526282169`, PA4 -> 1.0051036400602273`, 
  PA5 -> 1.0184217889730531`, PA6 -> 1.010180215980808`, 
  PA7 -> 1.0192687125814759`, PA8 -> 1.018857346320653`, 
  PD1 -> 1.0252421646198722`, PD2 -> 1.0183909319595217`, 
  PD3 -> 0.9981654199370373`, PD4 -> 1.003724509212916`, 
  PD5 -> 1.0182254041565721`, PD6 -> 1.0084940137495906`, 
  PD7 -> 1.0186704879949353`, PD8 -> 1.0186073133157483`, 
  PE1 -> 1.0390430275950355`, PE2 -> 1.0390430275950355`, 
  PE3 -> 1.0390430275950355`, PE4 -> 1.0390430275950355`, 
  PE5 -> 1.0390430275950355`, PE6 -> 1.0390430275950355`, 
  PE7 -> 1.0390430275950355`, PE8 -> 1.0390430275950355`, 
  PM1 -> 1.041111139247404`, PM2 -> 1.041112281813819`, 
  PM3 -> 1.04107563365962`, PM4 -> 1.0390430275950355`, 
  PM5 -> 1.0390430275950355`, PM6 -> 1.0390430275950355`, 
  PM7 -> 1.0390430275950355`, PM8 -> 1.0390430275950355`, 
  PQ1 -> 1.0265385178797473`, PQ2 -> 1.035552445261457`, 
  PQ3 -> 1.0214360532467015`, PQ4 -> 0.985830773491624`, 
  PQ5 -> 0.9227132438231194`, PQ6 -> 1.061165143980524`, 
  PQ7 -> 0.9927731210340657`, PQ8 -> 1.0445417247120758`, 
  PVA1 -> 0.7178136546371697`, PVA2 -> 0.7348090104812306`, 
  PVA3 -> 0.6832614691949576`, PVA4 -> 0.6988236179360032`, 
  PVA5 -> 0.71315789850611`, PVA6 -> 0.7129915540013146`, 
  PVA7 -> 0.7208437987059123`, PVA8 -> 0.7212556981513657`, 
  PX1 -> 1.0255042145439086`, PX2 -> 1.0343288240414`, 
  PX3 -> 0.9966008971543268`, PX4 -> 1.0049904518396577`, 
  PX5 -> 1.0182616405951943`, PX6 -> 1.0098146304813145`, 
  PX7 -> 1.0191110219246797`, PX8 -> 1.0187746984168868`, 
  QA1 -> 96483.52013031417`, QA2 -> 764996.3284723379`, 
  QA3 -> 580963.4583948016`, QA4 -> 375665.31910946453`, 
  QA5 -> 657989.0084889708`, QA6 -> 441948.89211707766`, 
  QA7 -> 104923.67343055189`, QA8 -> 803979.3133115796`, 
  QD1 -> 94575.21886770088`, QD2 -> 169852.1109582009`, 
  QD3 -> 427694.54718944087`, QD4 -> 359638.53162855323`, 
  QD5 -> 656811.3855251687`, QD6 -> 422037.92231309705`, 
  QD7 -> 102566.13589143129`, QD8 -> 797199.9413299251`, 
  QE1 -> 1908.674975404645`, QE2 -> 595164.3700064991`, 
  QE3 -> 163759.32997677548`, QE4 -> 16103.646316476452`, 
  QE5 -> 1179.495979684705`, QE6 -> 19907.333908031935`, 
  QE7 -> 2356.9378314700966`, QE8 -> 6774.465746904181`, 
  QF11 -> 7379.457810765676`, QF12 -> 37305.90195139228`, 
  QF13 -> 42220.67482946786`, QF14 -> 33620.41312659022`, 
  QF15 -> 52193.16869607288`, QF16 -> 51124.356780038645`, 
  QF17 -> 13359.031345787625`, QF18 -> 431606.9954598848`, 
  QF21 -> 59770.03176972253`, QF22 -> 635810.020628357`, 
  QF23 -> 188281.15701732496`, QF24 -> 167136.94982766494`, 
  QF25 -> 303421.28494094376`, QF26 -> 225668.63940484513`, 
  QF27 -> 70520.22999993713`, QF28 -> 86885.68641120465`, 
  QH11 -> 39548.75081491922`, QH21 -> 13705.79887755737`, 
  QH31 -> 382691.0626263847`, QH41 -> 137680.56737249502`, 
  QH51 -> 191795.01257501132`, QH61 -> 73807.03564881667`, 
  QH71 -> 64213.525214374684`, QH81 -> 77379.75740853828`, 
  QINT11 -> 7780.724242091927`, QINT12 -> 2983.057543739303`, 
  QINT13 -> 62197.0811075215`, QINT14 -> 0.`, 
  QINT15 -> 7827.624635565461`, QINT16 -> 5135.484314243567`, 
  QINT17 -> 0.`, QINT18 -> 6032.9163691310705`, 
  QINT21 -> 4810.452785877824`, QINT22 -> 37387.58590114959`, 
  QINT23 -> 74999.34472780843`, QINT24 -> 42627.19634685819`, 
  QINT25 -> 26940.90650222609`, QINT26 -> 4357.317664158915`, 
  QINT27 -> 650.2201491696313`, QINT28 -> 10381.635084316353`, 
  QINT31 -> 10986.39044376726`, QINT32 -> 15760.676135475933`, 
  QINT33 -> 103673.61692826312`, QINT34 -> 50627.50068968793`, 
  QINT35 -> 148321.8428364627`, QINT36 -> 34615.42916891911`, 
  QINT37 -> 6048.218955113914`, QINT38 -> 84752.57994253426`, 
  QINT41 -> 2097.0643921380074`, QINT42 -> 9082.00467234403`, 
  QINT43 -> 18849.40934344323`, QINT44 -> 25530.98241877317`, 
  QINT45 -> 28249.787998664906`, QINT46 -> 48505.02856141805`, 
  QINT47 -> 2585.25969219397`, QINT48 -> 38046.95330055487`, 
  QINT51 -> 2317.808012363061`, QINT52 -> 10629.652407325104`, 
  QINT53 -> 38336.833136159774`, QINT54 -> 23988.982662872968`, 
  QINT55 -> 44321.36994622299`, QINT56 -> 39283.390128639185`, 
  QINT57 -> 3104.654766305447`, QINT58 -> 86228.67564529595`, 
  QINT61 -> 1258.0432869463223`, QINT62 -> 4275.338253919775`, 
  QINT63 -> 17368.171119106933`, QINT64 -> 9337.49948898433`, 
  QINT65 -> 15649.546083782605`, QINT66 -> 9279.819116897337`, 
  QINT67 -> 1001.6905000721348`, QINT68 -> 21135.609444035617`, 
  QINT71 -> 727.6725533967469`, QINT72 -> 2592.7990663222527`, 
  QINT73 -> 9781.022682865483`, QINT74 -> 5603.295051098348`, 
  QINT75 -> 11115.512141870371`, QINT76 -> 4110.049756655381`, 
  QINT77 -> 5362.851770854032`, QINT78 -> 10712.14994796168`, 
  QINT81 -> 2404.738022097706`, QINT82 -> 9018.16291614388`, 
  QINT83 -> 25561.61983609057`, QINT84 -> 14841.374826613936`, 
  QINT85 -> 16591.522527479676`, QINT86 -> 12908.83928878744`, 
  QINT87 -> 1776.877885118212`, QINT88 -> 26095.37261392322`, 
  QINV1 -> 23336.717895261416`, QINV2 -> 5027.929349110679`, 
  QINV3 -> 582270.2567278288`, QINV4 -> 30.714290464940007`, 
  QINV5 -> 262062.51672432545`, QINV6 -> 1.023809682164667`, 
  QINV7 -> 0.`, QINV8 -> 0.`, QM1 -> 26485.06665972687`, 
  QM2 -> 8503.787759143468`, QM3 -> 626598.4128650116`, 
  QM4 -> 89010.10297991954`, QM5 -> 19624.543970341623`, 
  QM6 -> 89771.06456138313`, QM7 -> 9940.056265070823`, 
  QM8 -> 70510.24582588545`, QQ1 -> 158952.33077723757`, 
  QQ2 -> 221415.3612429972`, QQ3 -> 1.4233406267449094`*^6, 
  QQ4 -> 368196.75896987226`, QQ5 -> 707670.8437140494`, 
  QQ6 -> 153111.8028974798`, QQ7 -> 115416.86511278103`, 
  QQ8 -> 850151.2783974109`, QX1 -> 96483.52013031417`, 
  QX2 -> 764999.2892544841`, QX3 -> 580963.4583948016`, 
  QX4 -> 375662.35832731833`, QX5 -> 657990.9823437349`, 
  QX6 -> 441950.8659718418`, QX7 -> 104922.68650316984`, 
  QX8 -> 803975.3656020515`, WALRAS -> -17294.12708858342`, 
  WF1 -> 1.0380306584657037`, WF2 -> 1.0241180526643723`, 
  YE3 -> 1.7793979848686487`*^6, YF32 -> 1.7793979848686487`*^6, 
  YH1 -> 1.652408323906301`*^6, YF11 -> 694242.3239063012`, 
  YG -> 998198.4472290457`};
```

And

```
  sol = {EG -> 727784.9503927924`, EXR -> 1.0390430275950355`, 
  GSAV -> 270413.4968362533`, IADJ -> 1.023809682164667`, 
  PA1 -> 1.0243216030460287`, PA2 -> 1.034337694370249`, 
  PA3 -> 0.996595526282169`, PA4 -> 1.0051036400602273`, 
  PA5 -> 1.0184217889730531`, PA6 -> 1.010180215980808`, 
  PA7 -> 1.0192687125814759`, PA8 -> 1.018857346320653`, 
  PD1 -> 1.0252421646198722`, PD2 -> 1.0183909319595217`, 
  PD3 -> 0.9981654199370373`, PD4 -> 1.003724509212916`, 
  PD5 -> 1.0182254041565721`, PD6 -> 1.0084940137495906`, 
  PD7 -> 1.0186704879949353`, PD8 -> 1.0186073133157483`, 
  PE1 -> 1.0390430275950355`, PE2 -> 1.0390430275950355`, 
  PE3 -> 1.0390430275950355`, PE4 -> 1.0390430275950355`, 
  PE5 -> 1.0390430275950355`, PE6 -> 1.0390430275950355`, 
  PE7 -> 1.0390430275950355`, PE8 -> 1.0390430275950355`, 
  PM1 -> 1.041111139247404`, PM2 -> 1.041112281813819`, 
  PM3 -> 1.04107563365962`, PM4 -> 1.0390430275950355`, 
  PM5 -> 1.0390430275950355`, PM6 -> 1.0390430275950355`, 
  PM7 -> 1.0390430275950355`, PM8 -> 1.0390430275950355`, 
  PQ1 -> 1.0265385178797473`, PQ2 -> 1.035552445261457`, 
  PQ3 -> 1.0214360532467015`, PQ4 -> 0.985830773491624`, 
  PQ5 -> 0.9227132438231194`, PQ6 -> 1.061165143980524`, 
  PQ7 -> 0.9927731210340657`, PQ8 -> 1.0445417247120758`, 
  PVA1 -> 0.7178136546371697`, PVA2 -> 0.7348090104812306`, 
  PVA3 -> 0.6832614691949576`, PVA4 -> 0.6988236179360032`, 
  PVA5 -> 0.71315789850611`, PVA6 -> 0.7129915540013146`, 
  PVA7 -> 0.7208437987059123`, PVA8 -> 0.7212556981513657`, 
  PX1 -> 1.0255042145439086`, PX2 -> 1.0343288240414`, 
  PX3 -> 0.9966008971543268`, PX4 -> 1.0049904518396577`, 
  PX5 -> 1.0182616405951943`, PX6 -> 1.0098146304813145`, 
  PX7 -> 1.0191110219246797`, PX8 -> 1.0187746984168868`, 
  QA1 -> 96483.52013031417`, QA2 -> 764996.3284723379`, 
  QA3 -> 580963.4583948016`, QA4 -> 375665.31910946453`, 
  QA5 -> 657989.0084889708`, QA6 -> 441948.89211707766`, 
  QA7 -> 104923.67343055189`, QA8 -> 803979.3133115796`, 
  QD1 -> 94575.21886770088`, QD2 -> 169852.1109582009`, 
  QD3 -> 427694.54718944087`, QD4 -> 359638.53162855323`, 
  QD5 -> 656811.3855251687`, QD6 -> 422037.92231309705`, 
  QD7 -> 102566.13589143129`, QD8 -> 797199.9413299251`, 
  QE1 -> 1908.674975404645`, QE2 -> 595164.3700064991`, 
  QE3 -> 163759.32997677548`, QE4 -> 16103.646316476452`, 
  QE5 -> 1179.495979684705`, QE6 -> 19907.333908031935`, 
  QE7 -> 2356.9378314700966`, QE8 -> 6774.465746904181`, 
  QF11 -> 7379.457810765676`, QF12 -> 37305.90195139228`, 
  QF13 -> 42220.67482946786`, QF14 -> 33620.41312659022`, 
  QF15 -> 52193.16869607288`, QF16 -> 51124.356780038645`, 
  QF17 -> 13359.031345787625`, QF18 -> 431606.9954598848`, 
  QF21 -> 59770.03176972253`, QF22 -> 635810.020628357`, 
  QF23 -> 188281.15701732496`, QF24 -> 167136.94982766494`, 
  QF25 -> 303421.28494094376`, QF26 -> 225668.63940484513`, 
  QF27 -> 70520.22999993713`, QF28 -> 86885.68641120465`, 
  QH11 -> 39548.75081491922`, QH21 -> 13705.79887755737`, 
  QH31 -> 382691.0626263847`, QH41 -> 137680.56737249502`, 
  QH51 -> 191795.01257501132`, QH61 -> 73807.03564881667`, 
  QH71 -> 64213.525214374684`, QH81 -> 77379.75740853828`, 
  QINT11 -> 7780.724242091927`, QINT12 -> 2983.057543739303`, 
  QINT13 -> 62197.0811075215`, QINT14 -> 0.`, 
  QINT15 -> 7827.624635565461`, QINT16 -> 5135.484314243567`, 
  QINT17 -> 0.`, QINT18 -> 6032.9163691310705`, 
  QINT21 -> 4810.452785877824`, QINT22 -> 37387.58590114959`, 
  QINT23 -> 74999.34472780843`, QINT24 -> 42627.19634685819`, 
  QINT25 -> 26940.90650222609`, QINT26 -> 4357.317664158915`, 
  QINT27 -> 650.2201491696313`, QINT28 -> 10381.635084316353`, 
  QINT31 -> 10986.39044376726`, QINT32 -> 15760.676135475933`, 
  QINT33 -> 103673.61692826312`, QINT34 -> 50627.50068968793`, 
  QINT35 -> 148321.8428364627`, QINT36 -> 34615.42916891911`, 
  QINT37 -> 6048.218955113914`, QINT38 -> 84752.57994253426`, 
  QINT41 -> 2097.0643921380074`, QINT42 -> 9082.00467234403`, 
  QINT43 -> 18849.40934344323`, QINT44 -> 25530.98241877317`, 
  QINT45 -> 28249.787998664906`, QINT46 -> 48505.02856141805`, 
  QINT47 -> 2585.25969219397`, QINT48 -> 38046.95330055487`, 
  QINT51 -> 2317.808012363061`, QINT52 -> 10629.652407325104`, 
  QINT53 -> 38336.833136159774`, QINT54 -> 23988.982662872968`, 
  QINT55 -> 44321.36994622299`, QINT56 -> 39283.390128639185`, 
  QINT57 -> 3104.654766305447`, QINT58 -> 86228.67564529595`, 
  QINT61 -> 1258.0432869463223`, QINT62 -> 4275.338253919775`, 
  QINT63 -> 17368.171119106933`, QINT64 -> 9337.49948898433`, 
  QINT65 -> 15649.546083782605`, QINT66 -> 9279.819116897337`, 
  QINT67 -> 1001.6905000721348`, QINT68 -> 21135.609444035617`, 
  QINT71 -> 727.6725533967469`, QINT72 -> 2592.7990663222527`, 
  QINT73 -> 9781.022682865483`, QINT74 -> 5603.295051098348`, 
  QINT75 -> 11115.512141870371`, QINT76 -> 4110.049756655381`, 
  QINT77 -> 5362.851770854032`, QINT78 -> 10712.14994796168`, 
  QINT81 -> 2404.738022097706`, QINT82 -> 9018.16291614388`, 
  QINT83 -> 25561.61983609057`, QINT84 -> 14841.374826613936`, 
  QINT85 -> 16591.522527479676`, QINT86 -> 12908.83928878744`, 
  QINT87 -> 1776.877885118212`, QINT88 -> 26095.37261392322`, 
  QINV1 -> 23336.717895261416`, QINV2 -> 5027.929349110679`, 
  QINV3 -> 582270.2567278288`, QINV4 -> 30.714290464940007`, 
  QINV5 -> 262062.51672432545`, QINV6 -> 1.023809682164667`, 
  QINV7 -> 0.`, QINV8 -> 0.`, QM1 -> 26485.06665972687`, 
  QM2 -> 8503.787759143468`, QM3 -> 626598.4128650116`, 
  QM4 -> 89010.10297991954`, QM5 -> 19624.543970341623`, 
  QM6 -> 89771.06456138313`, QM7 -> 9940.056265070823`, 
  QM8 -> 70510.24582588545`, QQ1 -> 158952.33077723757`, 
  QQ2 -> 221415.3612429972`, QQ3 -> 1.4233406267449094`*^6, 
  QQ4 -> 368196.75896987226`, QQ5 -> 707670.8437140494`, 
  QQ6 -> 153111.8028974798`, QQ7 -> 115416.86511278103`, 
  QQ8 -> 850151.2783974109`, QX1 -> 96483.52013031417`, 
  QX2 -> 764999.2892544841`, QX3 -> 580963.4583948016`, 
  QX4 -> 375662.35832731833`, QX5 -> 657990.9823437349`, 
  QX6 -> 441950.8659718418`, QX7 -> 104922.68650316984`, 
  QX8 -> 803975.3656020515`, WALRAS -> -17294.12708858342`, 
  WF1 -> 1.0380306584657037`, WF2 -> 1.0241180526643723`, 
  YE3 -> 1.7793979848686487`*^6, YF32 -> 1.7793979848686487`*^6, 
  YH1 -> 1.652408323906301`*^6, YF11 -> 694242.3239063012`, 
  YG -> 998198.4472290457`};
```

I implement the following:

```
Inactivate[system,Equal]/.bench/.sol
```

To my surprise, it does not work as expected. It still generates `False` and `True` statements, while I want to see the equations inactivated.

Any idea why it is not working?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use [`Inactivate`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Inactivate.html) to prevent the `==` from evaluating:

```
Inactivate[x + y == m + n, Equal] /. sol
```

[image]

Note that we supply `Equal` (`==`) as second argument of `Inactivate` to only deactivate equality check, but not the additions.

In case the equation is stored in a variable, we need to use [`Evaluate`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Evaluate.html) to override the [`HoldFirst`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/HoldFirst.html) attribute of [`Inactivate`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Inactivate.html):

```
Inactivate[Evaluate@system, Equal] /. bench /. sol
(* long output... *)
```

Comment: I revised my question with the actual model I am using. Your `Code` in the answer does not work for this example. I am pretty sure that I make a mistake but where? Can you tell me where the problem is?

Comment: @TugrulTemel See the update to the answer

Comment: Now it worked as expected. Thank you for your kind help. Regards.